# APK package name issue in Google Play application upload

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Really stupid question I know. I am trying to upload my first application to Google Play and I am having issues uploading the APK. I get an error message saying:

```
Upload failed
You uploaded a debuggable APK. 
For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. 
Learn more about debuggable APKs.
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.
```

Does anybody know the package I need to use? And also will this be the case in all files in my Android Studio Project?

Sorry for my ignorance but it is my first time uploading and I am fairly new to this. I would really appreciate advice. Thanking you.

Answer (score 2):

Debuggable APK - If you're using the default Android Studio/Gradle setup, you have both a "debug" and "release" variant of your app build. You need to upload the "release" variant. If you haven't set up and backed up your release signing keychain yet, do so first.

Package name - this refers to the [`<manifest>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) element in `AndroidManifest.xml`. It has a similar format to Java package naming, and a few things are a little more convenient if it matches the package your source code is in, but it doesn't need to. Just change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
```

(where it says `com.example`) to something unique, and if you have any relative references elsewhere in the manifest (e.g. `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` etc) you'll need to make them fully qualified or move the Java class. Every app must have a different package name.